# All martingale measures price the attainable claim equally

Tags: mathematics, finance-mathematics, martingale, financial-engineering

**Background Information:**

This question is from Lectures on Financial Mathematics: Discrete Asset Pricing.

Theorem 3.2 First Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing - Suppose $\nu$ is any measure such that $S/S^{0}$ is a $\nu$-martingale. For an attainable claim $X$ with replicating strategy $\phi$ and $0\leq t\leq T$, we have
$$V_t(\phi) = E_{\nu}\left(X\frac{S_t^{0}}{S_T^{0}}|\mathcal{F}_t\right)$$

**Question:**

> Prove that:
>
> 1. All martingale measures price the attainable claim equally, and
> 2. if there is a martingale measure, then all replicating strategies for a given claim have the same value at all times.

I am sort of confused even where to begin, some guidance or suggestions may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Question 1, let $\phi$ be a replicating strategy, that is, $V_T(\phi) = X$. Then for any two martingale measures $u$ and $v$, from the *First Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing*,
\begin{align*}
E_u\left(X\frac{S_t^0}{S_T^0}\mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) = V_t(\phi),
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
E_v\left(X\frac{S_t^0}{S_T^0}\mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) = V_t(\phi).
\end{align*}
That is, all martingale measures price the attainable claim equally.

For Question 2, let $\mu$ be the martingale measure. Moreover, let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two replicating strategies, that is, $V_T(\phi)= V_T(\psi)=X$. Then, for any time $t$,
\begin{align*}
V_t(\phi) &= E_{\mu}\left(V_T(\phi)\frac{S_t^0}{S_T^0}\mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&= E_{\mu}\left(X\frac{S_t^0}{S_T^0}\mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&= E_{\mu}\left(V_T(\psi)\frac{S_t^0}{S_T^0}\mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&= V_t(\psi).
\end{align*}
That is, all replicating strategies for a given claim have the same value at all times.